# Error during travis ci integration in django and postgres in Github

Tags: django, postgresql, travis-ci, github-ci

I integrated travis in to my project where i used postgres but when i tried to test i got stuck in with an unkwown error i.e

```
 $ python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 629, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 554, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 157, in setup_databases
    test_databases, mirrored_aliases = get_unique_databases_and_mirrors(aliases)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 258, in get_unique_databases_and_mirrors
    default_sig = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS].creation.test_db_signature()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 295, in test_db_signature
    self._get_test_db_name(),
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 153, in _get_test_db_name
    return TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX + self.connection.settings_dict['NAME']
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
The command "python manage.py test" exited with 1.
```

I used postgres format as below in **.travis.yml** file

```
 services:
  - mongodb
  - postgresql

 before_script:
  - sleep 15
  - psql -c 'create database myapp_test;' -U postgres
```

What i will do?

Comment: either TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX or self.connection.settings_dict['NAME'] is None?

Comment: How can i know that?

Comment: can you paste your settings file's database part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Django's source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/creation.py), `TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX` is defined at line 12.

```
TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX = 'test_'
```

That means `self.connection.settings_dict['NAME']` is None

From [Django's document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#test), you need to setup test db in your settings file like

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'TEST': {
        'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',   <--- YOU NEED CONFIG HERE!
    },
},
```

Comment: I am getting something like this and after someting its failing  ====>Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "mytestdatabase" already exists
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'mytestdatabase', or 'no' to cancel:

Comment: The settings is your choice. If you use test database only once, choose yes. By the way, it's recommended to change the default database name 'mytestdatabase'  to your configuration.

Comment: For some reason my IDE sometimes jumps off pytest and tries the regular Django test runner. And I get this problem.